# parse deploy fail with authentication error when all the keys are set properly

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to deploy an app that I already deployed to in the past but started getting

```
Unable to authenticate app. 
Please make sure your applicationId and masterKey in "config/global.json" is correct
```

I got both `masterKey` and `applicationId` set in the file. I tried adding `jsKey` just to be sure. I also tried regenerating the master key and deploy but I still get the same error.

Wierd thing is that when I exeucte `parse releases` I get the list. So if this is an authentication error how could this request pass ?

Anyways, I'm stuck and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Happened to me too, just update the parse command line tool to the new version (from parse site).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved updating parse:

```
$ sudo parse update
```

but the binary was unzipped, see below:

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/parse
/usr/local/bin/parse: gzip compressed data, was "parse-osx-2.1.2", from Unix, last modified: Mon Jun 29 18:48:09 2015
```

so I copy and change the file name, unzip it and finally replace the original:

```
$ cp /usr/local/bin/parse ~/tmp/parse.gz
$ cd ~/tmp
$ gunzip parse.gz
$ sudo cp parse.gz /usr/local/bin/parse
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a parse.com ticket on this issue already but it is currently still an issue for me.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1606090639641473/?search_id

Comment: What you ended up doing ?